# GnuPG complaining I don't have a secret key but I do

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gpg

I am migrating machines I use for my backups. It uses GnuPG to encrypt/decrypt files. I moved my keys trying two different methods: exporting and copying the ~/.gnupg folder.

Both methods seem to work without issue. When I issue a `gpg -k` command, the output is identical on the new machine as it is on the old one. However, when I try to decrypt a backup archive on the new machine, I get the following error:

`GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log ===== 
gpg: setting pinentry mode 'loopback' failed: Not supported 
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID B5A6D4C1, created 2012-08-01 "<MY NAME REMOVED>" 
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
===== End GnuPG log =====`

I can clearly see that I have a key with that identifier:

`gpg -k` output on the new machine:

`/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
pub   rsa2048/C87A9934 2012-08-01
uid       [ultimate] <MY NAME REMOVED>
sub   rsa2048/B5A6D4C1 2012-08-01`

I am pretty sure I did something similar in the past without a hiccup, could anyone please help me figure out what the issue could be?

Old Machine:

- Linux 3.16.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 14 07:40:19 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.26
- libgcrypt 1.6.2

New Machine:

- Linux 4.0.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 7 06:47:54 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.3
- libgcrypt 1.6.3

**UPDATE**:

`gpg -K` output:

`sec   rsa2048/C87A9934 2012-08-01
uid       [ultimate] <NAME REMOVED>
ssb   rsa2048/B5A6D4C1 2012-08-01`

Comment: You showed a _public_ key, but _no secret key_.

Comment: my apologies, updated

Comment: Take a look https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Unattended_passphrase

Comment: I had the entry but I guess I didn't reload the agent, it appears to be working fine now!